# Check a chunk of text for tilde and ensure they are 60 characters apart. If not place a tilde inbetween

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a function in SQL that places a tilde every 60 characters, but the original text already has tilde's so , basically I want to change that if there is a tilde and the next tilde is under 60 characters away, then skip to the next tilde.  If its over 60 characters, then only then place a extra tilde.

My current function looks like;

```
function [dbo].[AddTilde] (
@string varchar(max),
@count int
)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @result varchar(max) = ''
    declare @token varchar(max) = ''

    while DATALENGTH(@string) > 0
    begin
        select @token = left(@string, @count) 
        select @string = REPLACE(@string, @token, '')
        select @result +=@token +case when DATALENGTH(@string)=0             then '' else '~' end
    end

    return @result
 end
```

Any help appreciated

Many Thanks

Comment: So, tildes must appear at most 60 characters apart, but there's no limitation on how close they can be? So if, e.g. there's a span of text with two tildes 70 characters apart, is there any restriction on where to *add* a tilde to make the text compliant? (Provided it's not within the first or last 10 of those 70)

Comment: Hi, no limitation on how close they can be, just the tilde needs to at most 60 characters apart.  If for example there is a chunk of text that is 70 characters between each tilde, then take this, and maybe place the tilde at the 60 point or 35 point (middle) is also sufficient.  The key is that no tilde are more then 60 characters apart. But if they are, only then intervene and insert another tilde.  Hope this makes sense. Many Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your current function?

Comment: Its puts tilder every 60 characters regardless of what is already in the text (text has tilde also, so we end up with many tilde).  What I would like is a tilde only if there is a gap of more then 60 characters in the current text between tilde before adding any more.  Many Thanks

Comment: You could use the patindex function to check the location of the next tilde character and shift to that point inside your loop if it is less than 60 characters away.

Comment: Can remove all existing tilde from your text first and then re-add it?

Comment: @R Ali, can you review answers and at least let us know if they helped you. If one of the answers did please accept the answer that you like the most.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @string1 VARCHAR(max),
        @string2 VARCHAR(max) = '',
        @i1 INT,
        @i2 INT

SET @string1 = '12345678901234567890~1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'

WHILE LEN(@string1) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @i1 = CHARINDEX('~',@string1)
            SET @i2 = @i1 - (ABS(@i1-60) + (@i1-60)) / 2 -- MINIMUM OF ~ LOCATION AND 60
        SET @i1 = LEN(@string1)
        IF  @i2 = 0 SET @i2 = @i1 - (ABS(@i1-60) + (@i1-60)) / 2 -- MINIMUM OF LENGTH OF @string1 LOCATION AND 60
        IF @i2 < 60
            BEGIN
                SET @string2 = @string2 + LEFT(@string1,@i2)
                SET @string1 = RIGHT(@string1,@i1-@i2)
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @string2 = @string2 + LEFT(@string1,60) + '~'
                SET @string1 = RIGHT(@string1,@i1-60)
            END
    END
```

Results: 12345678901234567890~123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890~1234567890123456789012345678901234567890

Answer (score 0):

This is based on my String Splitting function, which has a very good performance.

This function should be quite efficient, albeit hard to understand (I have added a few commenets in attempt to make it easier).

You can change internal parameters easily e.g. @Delimitor can be multiple characters

Test cases are included at the bottom.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AddTilde]
(
    @String VARCHAR( MAX ),
    @Count INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentPosition BIGINT, @NextDelimiterPosition BIGINT, @NextFixedPosition BIGINT, @NextPosition BIGINT,
        @DelimiterLength INT, @Delimiter VARCHAR( 5 ), @Result VARCHAR( MAX )

    -- Initialise
    SET @Delimiter = '~'
    SET @DelimiterLength = LEN( @Delimiter )
    SET @Result = ''
     -- Ensures we can terminate loop without using an extra IF condition, saves a few = 0 checks
    SET @String = @String + @Delimiter
    SET @CurrentPosition = 1 
    -- Check for next Tilde position
    SET @NextDelimiterPosition = CHARINDEX( @Delimiter, @String, @CurrentPosition ) 
    -- Initialise fixed increment position
    SET @NextFixedPosition = @Count
    -- Compare, which one is earlier and use that one. Handle cases where the next token begins with Tilde 
    SET @NextPosition = CASE WHEN @NextDelimiterPosition - @DelimiterLength > @NextFixedPosition THEN @NextFixedPosition ELSE @NextDelimiterPosition END

    WHILE @NextDelimiterPosition > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = @Result + SUBSTRING( @String, @CurrentPosition, @NextPosition - @CurrentPosition + 1 )
                -- Handle cases where the next token begins with Tilde and avoids doubling up Tildes
                + ( CASE WHEN @NextPosition = @NextDelimiterPosition THEN '' ELSE @Delimiter END )

        SET @CurrentPosition = @NextPosition + 1

        -- Increment fixed position
        SET @NextFixedPosition = @CurrentPosition + @Count - 1
        -- Check for next Tilde position
        SET @NextDelimiterPosition = CHARINDEX( @Delimiter, @String, @CurrentPosition )
        SET @NextPosition = CASE WHEN @NextDelimiterPosition - @DelimiterLength > @NextFixedPosition THEN @NextFixedPosition ELSE @NextDelimiterPosition END
    END

    -- Remove trailing Tilde
    SET @Result = SUBSTRING( @Result, 1, LEN( @Result ) - @DelimiterLength )

    RETURN @Result
END

/* Test Cases
SELECT dbo.[AddTilde]( 'ab~c~defghijkl~', 3 ) --> 'ab~c~def~ghi~jkl~'
SELECT dbo.[AddTilde]( '~ab~c~defghijkl', 3 ) --> '~ab~c~def~ghi~jkl'
SELECT dbo.[AddTilde]( 'ab~c~~defghijkl', 3 ) --> 'ab~c~~def~ghi~jkl'
SELECT dbo.[AddTilde]( 'abcdefghijkl', 3 )    --> 'abc~def~ghi~jkl'
SELECT dbo.[AddTilde]( 'a', 3 )               --> 'a'
*/
```